# What JPA annotation to use for list of lists?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity which holds a list of entities which in its turn holds a list of entities. I have a problem finding out the best way to accomplish that using JPA. I have read a lot but can't seem to find this case. Any of you have a suggestion?

```
@Entity
data class Invoice(
    @Id
    val Id: UUID,
    // What annotation should be used here? 
    val invoiceSpecifications: List<InvoiceSpecification>
)
```

```
@Entity
data class InvoiceSpecification(
    @Id
    val Id: UUID,
    // What annotation should be used here? 
    val invoiceSpecificationLines: List<InvoiceSpecificationLine>
)
```

```
@Entity
data class InvoiceSpecificationLine(
    @Id
    val Id: UUID
)
```

Adding som more info:

When I have used

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = “invoice_id”)
```

In a system that has pretty heavy load it has been nearly impossible to change the anything in the table. For example adding an index or a column results in a database lock. Maybe it is bad design to have a list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to a bunch of examples I have in [github](https://github.com/augusto/jpa-workshop/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ig/training/hibernate/domainmodel/onetomany) about different mappings.

The annotation you are missing is `@JoinColumn` for example:

```
@Entity
data class Invoice(
    @Id
    val Id: UUID,
    @JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", nullable = false)
    val invoiceSpecifications: List<InvoiceSpecification>
)
```

This will expect the column `invoice_id` in the invoice specification table, so it can be joined back with the invoice table.

And remember to add an Foreign key on invoice_id in your database!